# forecasting with optimised theta method (otm) using time series cross validation with R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, cross-validation, univariate

I want to do an out-of-sample forecast experiment using the optimised theta method (otm) on a time series. Further, time series cross validation with a fixed rolling window size should be applied. Therefore i tried to combine the `tscv` function with the `forecTheta` package:

```
## [Updated] 
library(forecTheta)
library(forecast)
library(tseries)

#y is the time series
y1 = 2+ 0.15*(1:20) + rnorm(20,2)
y2 = y1[20]+ 0.3*(1:30) + rnorm(30,2)
y =  as.ts(c(y1,y2))

#10 obs in the test set, and 40 obs in the training set
ntest <- 10
ntrain <- length(y)-ntest

# create a function with optimised theta method
# theta is within the bounds [1,5]
ftheta <- function(x,h){otm.arxiv(x,h=h,thetaList=seq(from=1,to=5,by=0.5),g="SE")}

# in each rolling window 40 obs are included
# h step ahead forecast
e <- tsCV(y,ftheta,h = 3,window=40)
```

However when i try to run this code the e1 vector, which includes the forecast errors, only has NA values. First I thought this would be due to no limit in the theta parameter, therefore i restricted this parameter. But this diddnt help.
Also i tried to implement/execute the forecast in the `forecTheta` package, but it diddnt work. [solved]

I have another question regarding the predicted values. For the 1-step ahead forecast the predicted values are obtained with the following:

```
#predicted values for h=1 
fc1 <- c(NA,y[2:50]-e[1:49,1])
fc1 <- fc1[41:50]
```

However I´m curious whether the predicted values for the 3-step ahead are coded correctly. Since the first 3-step ahead forecast is the prediction of the 43th observation, i guess the following line is wrong:

```
fc3 <- c(NA,y[2:50]-e[1:49,3])
fc3 <- fc3[41:50]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues present.

1. The first one is that `otm.arxiv()` does not follow the standard R practice of returning a fitted model that one applies `forecast()` to. Instead, it performs fitting *and* forecasting. To obtain a forecast from `otm.arxiv()`, you need to supply an `h` parameter to it:

   ```
   otm.arxiv(y,h=3,thetaList=seq(from=1,to=5,by=0.5),g="SE")
   ```
2. The second problem is that `otm.arxiv()` will apparently throw an error if `h`<3: whereas the previous line gives us a forecast, changing it to `h=2`

   ```
   otm.arxiv(y,h=2,thetaList=seq(from=1,to=5,by=0.5),g="SE")
   ```

   gives us the rather unhelpful error message

   ```
   Error in groe function: m<1
   ```

   (Incidentally, this is not due to your control parameters; we get the same error for `otm.arxiv(y,h=2)`.)

   You may want to bring this to the package maintainers' attention. At the very least, it would be good to see the restriction on `h` in the help page, and to have this error caught with a more informative error message.

So overall, you can get a useful `e1` error matrix by changing two lines as follows:

```
ftheta <- function(x,h){otm.arxiv(x,h=h,thetaList=seq(from=1,to=5,by=0.5),g="SE")}
e1 <- tsCV(y,ftheta,h = 3,window=40)
```

Of course, `e1` is now a 50 by 3 time series matrix, not a vector of length 50 any more, so you will need to adapt the rest of your code. And of course it still contains *some* `NA` values for the initialization part and where we can't forecast the full 3 periods at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! It works perfectly. Just a question for my understanding: when i change h in the e1 code line to h=6, i get different errors for the h=3 forecast, compared to when i use h=3 in the e1 code. Why is that?

Comment: That is a very good question. I would expect that there is something in the OTM algorithm where the *fitting* depends on the forecast horizon, so that supplying `h=6` yields a different *model* than `h=3`. (This would be a reason for the first point I raise, which is a nonstandard design decision.) Unfortunately, I have no understanding of the OTM, so I can't help you there. Sorry!

Comment: Good point! Sounds reasonable to me. Thanks again for your help.